# Find the 3rd order DE whose general solution is $ y= C_1e^{2x} + C_2\cos x + C_3 x\sin x $

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

My attempt

---

$$
\begin{matrix}
y  &=& C_1e^{2x} &+& C_2\cos x &+& C_3x\sin x\\
y' &=& 2C_1e^{2x} &-& C_2\sin x &+ &C_3(\sin x &+& x\cos x)\\
y'' &=& 4C_1e^{2x} &- &C_2\cos x &-& C_3(x\sin x&-&2\cos x)\\
y''' &=& 8C_1e^{2x} &+& C_2\sin x &-& C_3(3\sin x&+&x\cos x)\\
\end{matrix}
$$

Not really sure how to combine these such that I get a DE of form
$$Ay'''+By''+Cy'+Dy=0$$

Any help ?

Comment: Same way as before ... hoping that there is a solution !

Comment: Yeah I am hoping the same :) Actually I have asked previous question because I got stuck at $x\sin x$ part of this question.

Comment: Finding the DE is trivial if it were a simple $\sin x$ see [this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+y%27%27%27-2y%27%27%2By%27-2y%3D0) , the $x\sin x$ term seems to make it really hard to eyeball :O